# Timeout in Ext Direct

Tags: extjs

I'm using Ext Direct to communicate with the server side. My server side takes more than 45 seconds to return all the data to extjs. I can see in the network ( in chrome browser ), that my request was cancelled since the operation took more than 30 seconds.

Where can i override this setting ?

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ext-all-debug.js,

under

```
Ext.define('Ext.data.Connection', { timeout:30000
```

You can edit the timeout to a higher value, the default value is 30 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

I understand in Leo's answer that he suggests to edit directly ExtJS code, I don't think this is a good practice, all the more so as the parameter exists in the `REMOTING_API`:

```
Ext.app.REMOTING_API = {
    "url":"/usermanagement/extdirect/router",
    "actions":{"myService":[{"len":0,"name":"myMethod"}]},
    "type":"remoting",
    "timeout":120
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it's browser thing. It's not ExtJs breaking your connection attempt but the browser itself.

**Update**: I haven't tried using ExtDirect with huge data. And honestly speaking - you should not force your user to just wait on load such long time. It's very bad design. If you have something that takes that long - you need to provide some kind of feedback of the progress and break whole communication into smaller pieces.

Comment: I don't think so, the same happens in firefox too. Some answers in sencha forums suggest increasing timeout. But it's for ajax requests, i reckon the same scenario can happen for ext direct too. Thats why i'm concerned about the timeout.

Comment: sha, did you tried the above with either Chrome or Firefox ??

Comment: What 'above'? Not sure what you meant

Comment: 'Above' - i mean using Ext Direct to communicate with the server side, did u tried to load values in your form with huge records ( using Chrome & Firefox) and verified whether you're getting timeout or not ?

Comment: No. I haven't tried using ExtDirect with huge data. And honestly speaking - you should not force your user to just wait on load such long time. It's very bad design. If you have something that takes that long - you need to provide some kind of feedback of the progress and break whole communication into smaller pieces.

Comment: Thanks Many, please update if you tried with Ext Direct and facing the timeout issue.